# How to stress test a gpu?

Tags: gpu

How can I stress my gpu in order to test it? 100% load, fans screaming etc.

I need to know if the GPU works.

Glxgears, glmark2 return even worse fps than the i5 cpu

- Arch Linux
- Nvidia GTX 1080

Comment: Please install/reinstall/fix proprietary NVIDIA drivers - it looks like you're running on `nouveau` which cannot reclock your GPU to higher performance modes. Maybe you just need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Enabled me to able to rule out one failing gpu+psu combination (alongside screaming fans):

https://github.com/wilicc/gpu-burn